# Strange assert/comparison behavior with single PeriodIndex object from Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When trying to make a comparison with a PeriodIndex type object and subsequently writing a few data tests involving them I came across some confusing behavior.  Any clarification on why there is a difference in the way these statements are processed would be great.

```
> d = {'col1': ['a','b','c'], 'col2':pd.PeriodIndex(data=['2022-01-01','2021-05-01','2020-10-01'], freq='Q')}
> tdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=d)

> print(tdf.dtypes)
col1           object
col2    period[Q-DEC]
dtype: object

> print(tdf.col2[0])
2022Q1
> print(tdf.col2[0] == '2022Q1')
False
> print(tdf[tdf.col1 == 'a'].col2 == '2022Q1')
0    True

> assert tdf[tdf.col1 == 'a'].col2 == '2022Q1', 'doesnt match'
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

> assert all(tdf[tdf.col1 == 'a'].col2 == '2022Q1'), 'doesnt match'
# Passes no big deal
```

Accessing the same object in a different way makes the comparison go from False to True, and then wrapping the single assertion in `all` helps it to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case `tdf.col2[0] == '2022Q1'`, the comparison is done using the Python `==` operator and the result is `False` as you compare a **Period** (`pd.Period('2022Q1')`) **to a string** (the same way as `2 == '2'` yields `False`).

In the second case `tdf[tdf.col1 == 'a'].col2 == '2022Q1'`, you compare a **Series to a string**, which uses pandas comparison operations, see the following call stack:

```
  ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py(70)new_method()
-> return method(self, other)
  ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py(40)__eq__()
-> return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
  ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py(5623)_cmp_method()
-> res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py(269)comparison_op()
-> res_values = op(lvalues, rvalues)
  ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py(70)new_method()
-> return method(self, other)
  ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py(40)__eq__()
-> return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
  ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py(1008)_cmp_method()
-> other = self._validate_comparison_value(other)
  ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py(528)_validate_comparison_value()
-> other = self._scalar_from_string(other)
> ...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\period.py(331)_scalar_from_string()
-> return Period(value, freq=self.freq)
```

As you see, the string `'2022Q1'` [gets converted](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/bedd8f0170b5ff6cd0bab0e40f9bc5b95f6e1eec/pandas/core/arrays/period.py#L340-L341) to a `Period` before carrying out the actual comparison and hence the comparison of `Period('2022Q1')` with `Period('2022Q1')` is `True`.

I'm not sure if this conversion is intended behavior or a bug.

As for the assert part of your question: comparing a Series to something results in a boolean Series. When using a Series of booleans in a condition (`if` or `assert`), the result must be exactly one `True` or `False` value, not a Series of `True` or `False` values. As the error message says, you need to decide how you want to reduce the Series of booleans to a single boolean. In you special case the Series has only one element, but nevertheless it's a Series, hence the error (for a Series of length 1 it makes of course no difference if you use `any` or `all` or just `[0]`).

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for all that info.  The last part clears up the most annoying part for me.  A series of 1 is still a series as opposed to a single True/False.